# What’s the origin and history of using the word "stuff" to mean possessions?

Tags: meaning, etymology, formality, uncountable-nouns, register

When did the word “stuff” come to be used as casually as it is used today? I’m looking for an historical date for the sense meaning possessions.

Comment: Which slang usage of *stuff*?  There are several.

Comment: Sorry I eighty-sixed your question so quickly. I've edited it to clarify that there is no slang here. Now I’ll just twenty-three skiddoo outta here (after having carefully illustrated what slang actually is); roger that?

Comment: This is what defined it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLoge6QzcGY

Answer (score 5):

Early to mid 15th century?

*stuff*

> Property, esp. movable property, household goods or utensils; furniture;
>
> 111   Item to my wyf, all my stuff beyng at the Fasterne (1438)
>
> A grete red standerd full of stuff, locked with 2 lockes. (1464)

*The Oxford English Dictionary*

Answer (score 0):

According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=stuff), we have *"matter of an unspecified kind" (1570s)*, which, I think, fits the "Have you seen my stuff?" sense of the word as meaning "possessions".

Comment: OED says the "matter of an unspecified kind" sense  refers to "The general designation for solid, liquid, or (rarely) gaseous matter of any kind: used indefinitely instead of the specific designation, or where no specific designation exists. Often applied to a preparation or composition used for some special purpose," which stuff  is/are  not possessions.